# Proving the image of a line segment under an isometry is a line segment

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Is my proof correct? Any advice/comments?

If $F$ is an isometry and $L$ is a line segment then $F(L)$ is a line segment.

Assume $F$ is an isometry. Let Points $P, Q$ be the end-points of $L$ and $X$ be a point between them. Then $distance(P, Q) = distance(P, X) + distance(X, Q) = distance(F(P), F(Q)) = distance(F(P), F(X)) + distance(F(X), F(Q))$

Therefore $F(P), F(Q), F(R)$ are collinear and F(L) is a line.

Comment: You should tell us on which space the map $F$ acts.

Comment: 2D cartesian I think? This is from a basic math book, so whatever the default one is used in standard geometry. @ChristianBlatter

Comment: If one may use your criterion of collinearity as axiom or theorem your proof is o.k.